# Grabbing a relation's relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, where-clause

I'm using Rails 4 and I'm wondering how I can grab a **User's unique Services** based on all his existing Stacks. Basically:

```
User hasMany Stacks
Stacks hasMany Services
```

My attempt:

```
stacks = user.stacks
services = []
stacks.each do |stack|
  services << stack.services
end
```

And this works fine, however `services` is an Array and I lose all the nifty ActiveRecord functions such as order.

I can no longer order the `services` collection because it's an Array and not a ActiveRecord::Relation.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to `User` model and accessing the `user_services`

```
has_many :user_services, :through => :stacks, :source => :services
```